# AsyncSocket WHOIS connect

Tags: objective-c, ios, asyncsocket

I'm trying to connect to WHOIS servers (com.whois-servers.net:43) using  `GCDAsyncSocket`. I can connect and write to the server and the `didWriteDataWithTag:` gets called but there is no data. The WHOIS server does in fact sends a response but I cant read it.

```
NSLog(@"Connecting to \"%@\" on port %hu...", host, port);
    self.viewController.label.text = @"Connecting...";

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![asyncSocket connectToHost:@"com.whois-servers.net" onPort:43 error:&error])
    {
        DDLogError(@"Error connecting: %@", error);
        self.viewController.label.text = @"Oops";
    }

    NSString *requestStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"domain google.com\r\n\r\n"];
    NSData *requestData = [requestStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [asyncSocket writeData:requestData withTimeout:-1 tag:0];
    [asyncSocket readDataToData:[GCDAsyncSocket CRLFData] withTimeout:-1 tag:0];
```

Here is the `didReadData:`

```
- (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didReadData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag{
    DDLogInfo(@"socket:%p didReadData:withTag:%d", sock, tag);
    NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"Data: %i", [data length]);
}
```

Help?!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem using AsyncSocket. I never fully solved it, but found a close solution.

In **onSocket:willDisconnectWithError** (GapSocketCommand.m) you can get the current buffer when the connection fails by calling unreadData.

```
- (void)onSocket:(AsyncSocket *)sock willDisconnectWithError:(NSError *)err
{
NSLog(@"onSocket:willDisconnectWithError %@",err);
NSData * unreadData = [sock unreadData]; // ** This gets the current buffer

if(unreadData) {
    [self onSocket:sock didReadData:unreadData withTag:NULL]; // ** Return as much data that could be collected
} else {
    NSString* jsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"GapSocket.__onError(\"%d\",\"%@\");"
                      ,[sock userData]
                      ,[err localizedDescription] ];
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
    //[jsString release];
}
}
```

You'll have to modify it to apply to GCDAsyncSocket, but the solution should be the same.

Comment: Thanks. I got it fixed actually. Turned out that I had included GCDAsyncSocket.h twice and caused it to not call the functions. But if I try and call it a second time (which in .com, .net the whois process is a two step process needing two consecutive socket calls) this problem occurs.